# Unix file associations of mime-type with multiple extensions

Tags: install4j

Unix File Associations is a welcome new feature in install4j 8.
I'm trying to register multiple file extensions as file associations with the same mime-type with the install4j 8.0.1 Unix Shell Installer.

The "Create a File Association" action only seems to accept one file extension so I initially tried adding multiple of these actions with a different extension but the same mime-type. This seems valid, but when it translates into the actual installation of the application it appears that the mime-info XML files being made are named with the same mime-type and so all but one get overwritten.  This leads to only one file extension being associated with the mime-type.

I've also tried various separators (space, comma, semi-colon) in the file extension field, but this just ends up as a single unlikely looking extension in the mime-info XML file!
(e.g.

```xml
  <glob pattern="*.ext1,ext2" weight="60"/>
```

)

The mime-info XML format allows multiple `<glob>` elements, so the mime-info XML file could contain, e.g.

```xml
  <glob pattern=".ext1" weight="60"/>
  <glob pattern=".ext2" weight="60"/>
```

but I can't see a way to get to this from install4j8.

Is there a way?

Comment: I've also tried manually editing the .install4j file to add multiple `<property name="extension" type="string">ext1</property>` elements:
`<property name="extension" type="string">ext1</property>
<property name="extension" type="string">ext2</property>`
But that unsurprisingly didn't work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 8.0.1, this is indeed not possible. In 8.0.2, you will be able to specify multiple extensions separated by commas. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already implemented.